# CREATE A TIME SERIES PLOT in r with ggplot

Tags: r

I have problems with coding of  BIG DATA.

view(data)

| Year | Month | Deaths |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | 1 | 200 |
| 1998 | 2 | 40 |
| 1998 | 3 | 185 |
| 1998 | 4 | 402 |
| 1998 | 5 | 20 |
| 1998 | 6 | 48 |
| 1998 | 7 | 290 |
| 1998 | 8 | 15 |
| 1998 | 9 | 252 |
| 1998 | 10 | 409 |
| 1998 | 11 | 233 |
| 1998 | 12 | 122 |

My data goes until 2014. I would like to create a time series. In the x-Axis only some years are available in 5 year step. In the y axis the deaths of all month during the 2000 years are shown. I don't know how can I code that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is right because I didn't have any data. I have this from a programming book

```
data$date = as.Date(paste(data$Year, data$Month,1), format = "%Y %m %d")

ggplot(data,
       aes(
         x = date,
         y = Deaths,
        )) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Time series") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Deaths")
```

Update if you want a month break, you can use

```
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y", date_minor_breaks = "month")
```